# If data attribute above X number add class to element

Tags: javascript, this

I need to add Class **highpc** to each element with the data attribute of **procent**, which is bigger than 51. I've got a jQuery solution, but I need it in pure JavaScript. Can anyone help me? This is what I got so far:
**HTML**

```
<span data-procent="4" class="procent">4%</span>
<span data-procent="59" class="procent">59%</span>
```

**JS**

```
function highpc(){
    var procent = this.elem.getAttribute("data-procent");
    if (parseInt(procent) > 51) {
        procent.className=procent.className+" highpc";
    }
}
window.onload = highpc();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Zc8vY/1/

Comment: Have you checked the js console for errors? What is `this.elem`?

Comment: Hm, does that mean I have to ID every span first?  `var span1 = document.getElementById("span1");
var procent = span1.getAttribute("data-procent");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specified what is `this.elem`, and you haven't loop in your script. 
You are also using variable `procent` for getting the data-attribute from your element. Later, you are trying to use it for linking the element. Try updated code:

```
function highpc(){
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('procent');

    for(i=0;i<elements.length;i++) {
       var procent = elements[i].getAttribute("data-procent");
       if (parseInt(procent) > 51) {
           elements[i].className=elements[i].className+" highpc";
       }
    }
}
```

Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Zc8vY/4/

Answer (score 0):

This is your fixed function:

```
function highpc() {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.procent');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var procent = elements[i].getAttribute("data-procent");
        if (parseInt(procent) > 51) {
            elements[i].className += " highpc";
        }
    }
}

window.onload = highpc;
```

Note the last line: you don't need `()` after `highpc` because you want `window.onload` to be a reference to a function, not a result of execution.

References: [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) to select elements.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Zc8vY/3/

Answer (score 0):

Using pure javascript and implementing own getElementsByClassName.

```
function getElementsByClass(className){
    var celems = new Array();
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

    for(var i = 0; i < elems.length;i++){
        if(elems[i].className.indexOf(className) != -1){
            celems.push(elems[i]);
        }
    }

    return celems;
}

function highpc(){
    var elems =  getElementsByClass("procent");
     console.log(elems);
    for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){
        highpc_ex(elems[i]);
    }
}

function highpc_ex(elem){
    var procent = elem.getAttribute("data-procent");
    if (parseInt(procent) > 51) {
        elem.className=elem.className+" highpc";
    }
}

window.onload = highpc();
```

Answer (score 0):

[**WORKING FIDDLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zc8vY/7/)

```
function highpc() {
    var aSpans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
    for(var i = 0; i < aSpans.length; i++) {
        var eSpan = aSpans[i];
        var procent = eSpan.getAttribute("data-procent");
        if (procent != null && parseInt(procent) > 51) {
            eSpan.className += " highpc";
        }
   }
}
```

This is a similar variant to what others have already posted.  You might find this one to be more performant for larger sets of html.

Ref: [Why .getElementsByTagName() is faster than .querySelectorAll()](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/09/28/why-is-getelementsbytagname-faster-that-queryselectorall/)